Spring Boot API for Multiple Oracle Databases with Same Schema Using JPA/MyBatis
I want to create spring boot as backend and I have 6 branches with 5 separate oracle databases and same schema, I want to generate API to manipulate the data by using the Branche ID (for example 1,2,3,4,5 and 6) in each transaction for example:
http://x.x.x.x:8080/staff/1 for listing all the staff from the first branch then 2,3,4,5 and 6.
I don't want to have 6 separate applications and I prefer to use JPA or MyBatis, I can achieve it using JDBC but this will be tedious.
Can somebody help me with any idea?
I tried to use JPA and MyBatis
